# Count distinct field on Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do you count a distinct field in access?  I tried SELECT DISTINCTROW but it keeps counting instances of another linked table in access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery:

```
select count(*) as num_distinct_values
from (select distinct col
      from t
     ) as t
```